# Publicar na playstore não acerto o nome do apk

Tags: xamarin.android, google-play

Estou subindo uma apk ainda para o Alfa mas não estou conseguindo estou recebendo a mensagem de Erro

> "O nome do pacote APK precisa estar no formato "com.example.myapp".
>   Ele pode conter letras (a-z), números e sublinhados (_) e precisa
>   começar com um caractere em minúscula. São necessários 150 caracteres
>   ou menos."

só que o nome da aplicação é com.produto.empresa_01.apk

onde estou errando ?

Comment: esse parece ser o nome do arquivo gerado, você tem que verificar o nome do pacote, dá uma olhada no nome que aparece em `applicationId`  verifique tbm o seu AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema e não consegui resolver :\.

Comment: samuelrvg obrigado é essa chave mesmo que fica dentro do Manifest.xml

app-id e o nome tem que obrigatoriamente começar com letra minuscula dentro dele e o nome da apk deverá ser o mesmo descrito dentro do Manifest